# tmux key binding to pipe pane contents to program

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to get this key binding to work to pipe the contents of the current pane to a program of my choosing:

```
bind P command-prompt -I "vim -" \
    "capture-pane -eJ -S - -E -; \
    set-buffer -n PIPE; \
    new-window -n '|%1' 'tmux save-buffer -b PIPE - | %1'; \
    delete-buffer -b PIPE"
```

-- but it always results in tmux reporting `no buffer PIPE`. This text is usually shown and overwritten too quickly for me to even notice it; I managed to elicit it by using `sleep 10` as the command name to pipe the output to.

I chose to rename the automatically-named buffer created by `capture-pane` because otherwise the `new-window` invocation seemed to reset tmux's current/default buffer to whatever I had last copied in copy mode. As far as I can tell, the new buffer should be renamed `PIPE`.

I have a similar but simpler binding, which outputs the contents to a file instead of a pipe, working perfectly:

```
bind H command-prompt -I "tmux_#W.txt" \
    "capture-pane -eJ -S - -E -; \
    save-buffer '%%'; \
    delete-buffer"
```

If I run the commands in it one by one, the program does receive the text of the pane as it would from any other pipe. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just realized I was partially wrong about needing to rename the buffer -- that seemed to be the case when I was using `run-shell`, but now that I'm using `new-window` it seems to be unnecessary. If I don't rename it and refer to the name `PIPE` in subsequent commands, things work fine, except that the buffer doesn't get deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is a race between the `new-window` and the `delete-buffer` commands: that is, the buffer "PIPE" is deleted before it can be piped into vim or whatever program you want to be executed.

The following ugly hack that sleeps a second before calling `delete-buffer` fixes the problem for me:

```
bind P command-prompt -I "vim -" \
    "capture-pane -eJ -S - -E -; \
    set-buffer -n PIPE; \
    new-window -n '|%1' 'tmux save-buffer -b PIPE - | %1'; \
    run-sh 'sleep 1 && tmux delete-buffer -b PIPE'"
```